# How to update the Baldur's Gate engine to the latest version without installing Baldur's Gate 2?

Tags: baldurs-gate

I would like to have all the latest Infinity Engine stuff like high resolution modes, highlight items feature, updated game mechanics etc. But I would like to save hard drive space (yes, it matters to me) by avoiding putting all the games to it while I only seek to play the original Baldur's Gate now. Is this possible to update the engine to the latest version without installing the newer games content?

Comment: Higher resolution modes and extra features will automatically take up more space, because more detail = more space.  About the only thing you could remove would be the story content itself, and that's probably the smallest thing out of the list.

Answer (score 2):

High resolution modes are possible in BG1 without BG2/BGT/Tutu by using [The Widescreen Mod](http://www.gibberlings3.net/widescreen/).

The problem then becomes the GUI, which does not stretch to fill the screen. This can be fixed somewhat with [TWM_GUI](http://athkatla.cob-bg.pl/viewtopic.php?t=3257). The problem with that is it adds some really ugly background images to the menu screens in the game - unless you enjoy inverted maps and SPAAAAAAACE in your Baldur's Gate.

Highlight items is only possible in BG1 if you have BG2: Throne of Bhaal and use Tutu or BGT, unless there's a mod that adds this functionality to BG1 that I'm unaware of.

As for game mechanics, which ones specifically are you missing? A number of things changed between BG1 and BG2, some of which you may be able to find mods for (such as multi-class grand mastery). [BG1 Tweaks](http://www.gibberlings3.net/bg1tweaks/index.php) may be what you're looking for. I'm not aware of a mod for BG1 that adds dual-wielding though.

If you can afford the disk space, you should probably install BG1 and BG2:ToB, then install [EasyTutu](http://usoutpost31.com/easytutu/), then delete your BG1 install. In order to use Tutu BG2 has to stay on your drive, but BG1 doesn't.

Comment: I have mentioned "game mechanics" just for the matter of taste. To be honest all I actually want are high resolution, items highlighting and endless bags for scrolls and other items like those met in Icewind Dale, I am really a crazy item collector :-]

Comment: I realize now it's been a few months since you asked. If you haven't already noticed, it's pretty impossible not to run out of inventory space in BG1 unless you ignore a ton of loot. There's a mod that allows you to stack certain items like rings, but it's not really worth it in my opinion. There aren't very many items in the game you will want that you won't find just laying around at some point.